Cakephp 4 how to get request (or controller name) in Application.php?
I need to be able to get the request or just the controller name in the middleware so I can do some conditional logic.  I am trying to modify the middleware() function in Application.php.  Based on the controller called in the request, I will add or not add certain other middleware. All the examples I can find talk about creating a custom middleware and adding it to the middleware queue. I tried this but I am unable to pass variables back to the main middleware() function.  Is it possible to get the request/controller in the main middleware() without having to create a customer middleware?  If that is not possible, how do I pass a variable back to middleware() from a custom middleware so that I can conditionally add or not add other middleware in the middleware queue?
Thanks for any help.
Searching for sample code in chatgpt, but can't determine how to get the request in the middleware() function in Application.php.

The "main middleware function" does not actually execute any of the middlewares. It sets up the queue of middlewares that will be executed a little later. So there's definitely no possibility of passing anything back to that function from a middleware; it's long since finished running before any of the middlewares execute.

It is possible to add middleware conditionally based on the route, see Route Scoped MIddleware.
